# retrieving String from Core Data Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, core-data, split

I have the following code to access the Core Data database and retrieve a string. (formatted xx:xx:xx)

I am aiming to loop through the times (String) to find the largest duration. My code is below:

```
func loadHighscore() {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var score = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Scores")
    score.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var scores : NSArray = context!.executeFetchRequest(score, error: nil)!

    println("\(scores.count) scores available")

    var highestMins = 0
    var highestSecs = 0
    var highestFrac = 0

    var currentMins : Int
    var currentSecs : Int
    var currentFrac : Int

    if scores.count > 0 {

        var time = scores.firstObject!
        var myStringArr = time.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

        currentMins = myStringArr[0] as! Int
        currentSecs = myStringArr[1] as! Int
        currentFrac = myStringArr[2] as! Int

        if currentMins > highestMins {
            highestMins = currentMins
            highestSecs = currentSecs
            highestFrac = currentFrac
        }

        else if currentMins ==  highestMins {
            if currentSecs > highestSecs {
                highestMins = currentMins
                highestSecs = currentSecs
                highestFrac = currentFrac
            }
            else if currentSecs == highestSecs {
                if currentFrac > highestFrac {
                    highestMins = currentMins
                    highestSecs = currentSecs
                    highestFrac = currentFrac
                }
                    //accounts for the times being identical
                else {
                    highestMins = currentMins
                    highestSecs = currentSecs
                    highestFrac = currentFrac
                }
            }
        }

        println("Highscore: \(highestMins):\(highestSecs):\(highestFrac)")
    }
    else {
        println("0 scores returned")
    }

}
```

when I complied this i get an error

> 'due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSManagedObject componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance'.

I think this may be caused as i am not fetching/splitting the string values from the Core Data database correctly.

Any ides on how to retrieve this string correctly would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: `scores` is an array of `NSManagedObjects` and not `Strings`, in your "Scores" Entity do you have a variable for storing the `String`?

Comment: Hi @Ollie, yes I have a variable called 'time' which holds string values. This may be why i got confused!

Comment: Well in which case, Will's answer below should fix your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreData can't store Strings. It only stores NSManagedObjects. The result of the fetch you executed is list of NSManagedObjects.
You need to create a Entity with a field to store the time.

For example, create in the xcdatamodeld a entity called Score, with a field of type String called time.

Then, in your code, do this:

```
        (...)
        var score = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Score")
        score.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var scores : NSArray = context!.executeFetchRequest(score, error: nil)!

        println("\(scores.count) scores available")

        var highestMins = 0
        var highestSecs = 0
        var highestFrac = 0

        var currentMins : Int
        var currentSecs : Int
        var currentFrac : Int

        for score in scores {

            var time = score.valueForKey("time") as! String
            var myStringArr = time.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        (...)
```

Comment: Hi. When i implement this i get the following error:
    CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null), reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";

Comment: Do you still need the old dataBase? If not, clean/build the project, reset the simulator or/and uninstall the application in the device. It is because you changed the entity.

Comment: I have reset the simulator and still get the same error. I also tried deleting the Entity 'Score' and creating a new one and still failed

Comment: Thats strange. Deleting the entity will not help, but this is clearly a problem because your old model was different. Try to clean your project, reset the simulator and then go to the Simulator >> reset content and settings (from navbar)

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks. I have tried this however it didn't work. The line of code 'var time = scores.valueForKey("time")' has a warning associated to it saying 'variable "time" inferred to have a type "AnyObject"?, which may be unexpected'. Also on the line 'var myStringArr = time.componentsSeparatedByString(":")' it is saying that 'time' is an optional and i have to force unwrap it which when i do i get the error 'erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Comment: I have just tweaked this and got it working. I changed the following: 

'let results: [AnyObject]
        results = context!.executeFetchRequest(score, error: nil)!
        println(results.count)
        
        for i in results {
            var time = i.valueForKey("time")
            var myStringArr = time!.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
            println(time!)

        }'

Comment: Yes, I changed my code, I was accessing scores to find time, it was wrong. Now The code is ok too.